# python pisa utf8 issue

Tags: python, pdf, utf-8, pisa

I am trying to convert a local HTML to a PDF, but the html document has non-ASCII characters that end up broken in the PDF. Why does `pisa` not work for all UTF-8 characters?

```
with open('file.html') as m:
  data = m.read()
  m.close()        
  pisa.CreatePDF(data, file('final.pdf', 'w'))
```

Comment: I've no experience with `pisa`, but have you ensured that your HTML has the proper character set declared?

Comment: it does and everything displays properly in browser

Comment: What do they actually look like in the PDF? Can you provide a screenshot and the actual bytes producing the problems?

Comment: Maybe `pisa` wants straight unicode.  Try adding `data = data.decode('UTF-8')` in there.

Comment: Is `data` an encoded byte string, or a `unicode` object?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637229/is-there-a-way-to-generate-pdf-containing-non-ascii-symbols-with-pisa-from-djang

Comment: This is a screenshot of the output... http://i.imgur.com/pFKXz.png
all the broken text is supposed to look like this മാഗോഗ്, മാദായി, യാവാന്‍, തൂബാല്‍, മേശെക്

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: @Keith Randall it generates a completely blank PDF

Answer (score 7):

Got it. This needs to be at the top of your generated content:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Helped me a lot in pdf generation from Django template.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped using the encoding option with **encoding='utf-8'**:

```
pisa.CreatePDF(html.content, dest=pdfFile, encoding='utf-8')
```