# How to generate and download pdf in django?

Tags: python, django, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfkit

```
html_data = os.path.abspath("apps/dashboard/templates/pdfdata.html")
response_data['status'] = False
pdfkit.from_file(html_data, 'out.pdf')
```

By using pdfkit and the above code, pdf generated successfully.
Now I want to download this generated pdf.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django pdf export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821087/django-pdf-export)