# Python HTML to PDF with full support for CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am working on a Python/Django project, where I have to convert some of my highly styled html content to PDF. Currently I am using the `wkhtmltopdf` library. While the conversion works almost perfectly there are some issues regarding CSS3 and HTML5 support. Some of the styles don't convert correctly to pdf and I have to alter the CSS and HTML to make it more print friendly so I can convert to PDF correctly. Until lately I thought there is no tool that could make 100% conversion but than I found this with an online demo http://www.html-to-pdf.net/free-online-pdf-converter.aspx which has a far superior HTML5 and CSS3 support, but it is written for .NET. Is there anything with this level of conversion with Python support?

Note: I will have lots of HTML pages that will need conversion and tweaking the CSS for each one is not a good option for me. I would need something that could make a 100% conversion regarding the styling from HTML to PDF.

Comment: Were you able to find some solution?

Comment: It is 2017 now , does the libs you used be 100% ?

Comment: Hey, It is 2019 now, did you find any python library, that supports full css3 and html5 .

Comment: @Ales Malticic do think my answer will help other with your question?

Comment: Its 2021, any lucky with a good lib

Answer (score 7):

You should check [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.org/), It supports most of the CSS3 and HTML5, at the moment it doesn't support `flex-wrap: wrap` propierties as far as I know.

I used [xhtml2pdf](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf) with `Reportlab` it supports **some** CSS3 (supports HTML5 CSS 2.1). I don't recommend it when you have a better and simple tool like weasyprint.

[Simple Django Tutorial with weasyprint](https://micropyramid.com/blog/generate-pdf-files-from-html-in-django-using-weasyprint/)

Answer (score 1):

If you or someone else is still looking for some solutions, check out this:
[Render HTML to PDF in Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site)

also
https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf
or
https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit

I hope this will help most of you.

Comment: I you read my question is that I already have a solution which works 97% for css3 properties, but I have found some other solution that works 100% for css3 (unfortunately not for python) and as far as I know there is no python lib that would accomplish that.

Comment: Your question was if there is something for python. And yes there is something in python which also include html5 and css3 when porting html to pdf.

Comment: please read my question again carefully. I said that I already use a Python solution that supports html5 and css3(wkhtmltopdf) but that support is not 100%. There are tons of questions on here for simple conversion. All your solutions either use the same lib or have the same flaws, and none of them can 100% transform a css3 based html page to a pdf without noticeable differences.