# django wkhtmltopdf-different page orientation in single pdf

Tags: django, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I want to create a pdf  using wkhtmltopdf with different orientation(for eg: one page be portrait and another page be landscape and again portrait like that), i tried in css but it does not work.please help, thanks in advance.

my views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse

class pdf_view(View):
    template = 'temp1.html'
    filename = 'file1.pdf'
    header_template='header_temp.html'
    footer_template='footer_temp.html'
    context= {'title': 'PDF GENERATION'}

    def get(self, request):
        response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                   template=self.template,
                                   filename = self.filename,
                                   header_template=self.header_template,
                                   footer_template=self.footer_template,
                                   context= self.context,
                                   )
        return response
```

my template.html

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>{{ title }}</title>
        <style type="text/css">
               #landimg img{
                   margin-top:20px;
                   height:auto;
                   width:auto;
                   }
               #portimg img{
                   height:auto;
                   width:auto;
                   margin-top:50px;
                   }
               @page #port{
                   size:letter;
                   }
               @page #land{
                   size:landscape;
                   }
           </style>
        </head>
       <body>
        <div id='port'>
           <img src="/static/images/2_180_3.jpg" alt="" />
       </div>
        <div id='land'>
             <img src="/static/images/land.JPG" alt="" />
        </div>  
       </body>
     </html>
```

@page css was not working while printing pdf, it was in portrait as default.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
 @page{
      size:letter;
 }
 @page land{
       size:landscape;
 }
```

In wkhtmltopdf only few of the css properties are available to work with UI design.

```
<div>
     <img src="/static/images/2_180_3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
  <pdf:nexttemplate name="land"/> 
  <pdf:nextpage/>   
</div>
<div>
   <img src="/static/images/land.JPG" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amar Kamthe , i tried your css code but still all pages are in portrait only, landscape not working.

Comment: i want to know is there any possibility to use both portrait and landscape in single document using wkhtmltopdf, the documentation says cmd_options for orientation is global, so i put the cmd_options = {'orientation' : 'landscape/portrait'} it works fine for single orientation, but i need both.

Comment: @Sansiva : I have tried using pisa module. Its the html 2 pdf converter. In my case the single pdf had portrait as well as landscape pages. See the 1st answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site. This is the example of how to use pisa and then you can add above code for landscape and portrait view.

Comment: hi Amar, i used pisa module it works fine as you said,thank u so much.. but .svg format images does not display in pdf, Is there any way to display svg images without converting to jpeg,png??

Comment: No worries at all @Sansiva, glad I could help. About the svg image, it doesn't seems that there is a way to display svg image using pisa module. I have worked on displaying png.