# How to pass django variable to non served html file

Tags: python, django

I have a html invoice file. Currently my django app is not serving it. I want to pass some variable to it and then download it as a `HttpResponse`.

My invoice file folder structure is like:

```
--someFolder/invoice(folder)
               |__ index.html
               |__ style.css
               |__ logo.png
```

I have a function in my models file like:

```
def createInvoice(self, po_number):
    po = self.purchase_orders.find_one({'po_number':po_number})

    total_po_qty = po['total_po_qty']
    po_subtotal = po['po_subtotal']
    tax_value = po['tax_value']
    shipping_value = po['shipping_value']
    total_po_value = po['total_po_value']
    vendor_name = po['vendor_name']
    tax_percent = po['tax_percent']
    tax_type = po['tax_type']
    expiry_date = po['expiry_date']
    sku_list = po['sku_list']
```

How can i pass these variables to the html file?
I can render the file as a view but i dont want to do that since it is bound to a download button.

Comment: What does this mean? What is the point of "passing variables" to an HTML file that you're not even serving?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the goal is, since the description sounds contradictory. The view normally responds with an HTML generated (rendered) on the fly based on a template. The view can pass parameters to the renderer.

Comment: I was thinking of using wkhtmltopdf to convert that page as a pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** "pass python variables" to a static HTML file, period, so you **do** have to use a view (and turn your HTML file into a template FWIW).

wrt/ "download" thing, forcing file download from a Django view is quite easy and documented - but then HTML is probably not the appropriate format, you may want to [generate a PDF instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/). NB : you may want [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site) for a way to generated PDF from HTML