# How to turn a Django webpage into a PDF

Tags: django, pdf

I would like to add a feature to my Django website where the user can click on a link saying "Save as PDF". I would like this link to 1) produce a **slightly different version** of the page the user is currently on and 2) generate a PDF file in a separate window that the user can then save to wherever he or she wants.

All of the PDF functions I came across related to Django assumed that you already had a PDF that you wanted to render. In this case though, I want to create a PDF based on the content of the current page. Any idea how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: ay be this help:
[Render HTML to PDF in Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool [WeasyPrint](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjU1oK2i6HVAhUITLwKHfu5CeQQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmicropyramid.com%2Fblog%2Fgenerate-pdf-files-from-html-in-django-using-weasyprint%2F&usg=AFQjCNE0PECGsCVhqzAhR_kP4FhcbmyZ1A). You can use it with Django

Answer (score 0):

Any webpage is just a HTML basically so any html to pdf library would work. But this one is specifically built for django. Hope this helps. 
[Documentation for django-wkhtmltopdf](http://django-wkhtmltopdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) You can accept the answer if you like it.