# How to export Django Template to pdf

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to convert django template to pdf using pdfkit, wkhtmltopdf was installed but I'm getting error like

> OSError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. 
>   error:QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

How to solve this issue or suggest me any other better way to export django template to pdf?

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import pdfkit

def generatepdf(request):
    data={}
    template = get_template('template_name.html')
    html = template.render(data)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
    filename = "sample_pdf.pdf"
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="' + filename + '"'
    return response
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192642/wkhtmltopdf-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to-display

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render HTML to PDF in Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://pypi.org/project/django-wkhtmltopdf/. It works without issue and the pdf has no issue in terms of layout. It is very easy to implement.