# Django Convert HTML that has JS charts to PDF

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts, chart.js

I am trying to build an application that can make Report Cards.
These report cards have charts made in ChartJs showing student's growth and development each semester. 
I need to make these cards into PDF or an Image and then download them.
I have already tried XHtml2pdf and it is not able to generate the charts.
I just wanna know, is there a way I could covert my HTML ( with JS charts) into PDF or Image.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site

Comment: I didn't get my answer.