# Django App - Button Download home page to pdf

Tags: python, html, css, django, button

i am working on an django App

On my html page " results.html "
i want to add a button to download the page to pdf

How is it possible,  please ?
What i have to write in the fonction" download_pdf" in the file views.py?

.html :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'download_pdf' %}" role="button">Download pdf</a>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('views.download_my_pdf', views.download_pdf, name="download_pdf"),

]
```

views.py :

```
def download_pdf(request):

        return response
```

Comment: Can you share the entire error page to get more info? In any case, the error says that your are passing a string, not a file to read. Maybe you can solve it just adding this: response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'

Comment: Do you want to download a pdf file from your server or do you want to convert the web page to a pdf file and download it?

Comment: Of course, because you are not using FileWrapper function in a right way. You are passing just a string with a filename to FileWrapper. This has no sense. What exactly is the content of your PDF? You can find some examples of FileWrapper here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/78219/wsgiref.util.FileWrapper

Comment: On my html page " results.html " i want to add a button to download the web page to pdf and download it

How is it possible, please ? What i have to write in the fonction" download_pdf" in the file views.py?

.html : <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'download_pdf' %}" role="button">Download pdf</a>

Comment: urls.py   :                                                                                                                     
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('views.download_my_pdf', views.download_pdf, name="download_pdf"),

]

Comment: views.py:                                                                                                                                         def download_pdf(request):

        return response

Comment: the content of my PDF page is the content of my html page : "results.html" . Iwant to convert the web page to a pdf file and download it

Comment: try this[reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1377652/16502488) from stack overflow good luck with your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a HTML page to a PDF on-the-fly and send its result as a response in Django with [Django Weasyprint](https://github.com/fdemme/django-weasyprint). E.g., have a look at the examples with `WeasyTemplateResponseMixin`.